# "Arraylist not applicable in double" error

Tags: android, eclipse, arraylist

Im using an external library. and after changing the array from array list. I got this error:

```
The method add(double, double) in the type XYSeries is not applicable for the arguments (int, ArrayList<Double>)
```

this is my code:

```
ArrayList<Double> addition = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        additionSeries.add(x[i], addition);
```

an error in `additionSeries.add`

what could be the solution for this?

**UPDATE**

```
if(Game.isNewScore) {
    if (addition.size() == 5){
        addition.remove(0);
    }
    addition.add(Game.score);
}
```

this is my code in add value in my arraylist

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: graphical chart sir. I have a project that uses a library. and because I want to have a FIFO algorithm in my project I use arraylist. the codes seems to work before I change it from `array` to `arraylist`

Comment: Method "add" in the "XYSeries" doesn't work with those parameters, you could maybe try and use an Android method for ArrayList "add(int index, E object)", or in your case for adding an ArrayList, the method "addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> collection) ???

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is the missuse of [`XYSeries`](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/index.html?org/achartengine/model/XYSeries.html) method `add`

You can only add numbers as in :

```
add(double x, double y);
```

Here you tried to add a list of number as a second parameter.
To validate, your code should look like this

```
// Considering addition `ArrayList` contains 5 or less elements
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    for (Double additionEntry : addition) {
        additionSeries.add(x[i], additionEntry);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering sir. heres my code in add method `addition.add(Game.score);`

Comment: Edited answer: Big missunderstanding from me... *should sleep*

Comment: I use aChartEngine sir. I implement the codes. I just wanted to accept the arraylist in  add method of XYSeries Class from the aChartEngine.